# Unrecognized Resource Types

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, serverless-framework

I'm trying to understand how Serverless works. I've gone through a lot of their docs / tutorials, however when I get to the part where I want to build something specific, like an RDS instance, I have no frame of reference for what the MVP will look like.

I found this [Q/A post](https://forum.serverless.com/t/create-a-resource-in-a-vpc-aws-rds/6361/4) that showed what looked to be the basics for standing up an RDS instance. I swapped out the region for a more local one, then tried it out:

```
service: sandbox
app: sandbox
org: # omitting 

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

resources:
  Resources:
    Vpc:
      Type: AWS:EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        InstanceTenancy: default

    PublicSubnet:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/18
        VpcId:
          Ref: Vpc

    PrivateSubnet1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: ca-central-1a
        CidrBlock: 10.0.64.0/18
        VpcId:
          Ref: Vpc

    PrivateSubnet2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: ca-central-1b
        CidrBlock: 10.0.128.0/18
        VpcId:
          Ref: Vpc

    Database:
      Type: AWS::RDS:DBInstance
      Properties:
        Engine: aurora
        EngineVersion: 5.6.10a
        DBInstanceClass: db.r5.large
        DBName: MyDatabase
        MasterUsername: test
        MasterUserPassword: # ommitting
        DBSubnetGroupName:
          Ref: DBSubnetGroup
        VPCSecurityGroups:
          - Ref: DatabaseVpcSecurityGroup

    DBSubnetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
      Properties: 
        DBSubnetGroupName: PrivateDbSubnet
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: PrivateDbSubnet
        SubnetIds:
          - Ref: PrivateSubnet1
          - Ref: PrivateSubnet2

    DatabaseVpcSecurityGroup:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
      Properties:
        GroupName: DBSecurityGroup
        GroupDescription: Allow local access
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/16
            IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 3306
            ToPort: 3306
        VpcId: 
            Ref: Vpc
```

When I attempt to deploy this with Serverless, I get the following error:
`The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS:EC2::VPC, AWS::RDS:DBInstance]`

I can see that these resources exist on AWS:

- [AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html)
- [AWS::EC2::VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html)

So... what does this error mean? What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typos in your resource type. In both cases you have a single colon (:) where you should have a double colon (::)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and the solution was to add the following line to the top of my template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

When using SAM specific resource types like `AWS::Serverless*` you must define the `AWS:Serverless` transform in your Cloudformation Template. To do so, include the `Transform` property at the top of the template.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though for anyone reading this today this answer does not help much. Maybe expand it by explaining what this line does?

Comment: This was the solution for me. I was using a Cloudformation template that did not have this property defined in the `template.yaml` file yet I was using the Serverless Macro expansion types for SAM. This manifested in an error like: `Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Serverless::Api]`

Comment: Thanks for the improved edits, @dsandor!

Comment: May I know, where have you found those instructions?

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error Unrecognized "Resource Types", it means there is a syntax problem in your code.

Check for typos after "Unrecognized resource types":

```
Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Dynamo::Table]
```

In this case, it should be

```
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
```